# Update objects in one list based on values from second one using streams

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have two corresponding lists:

```
public class BookOverallData {
    private Long idOfBook;
    private String title;
    private String authour;
    private BigDecimal basePrice;
    private Integer discountRate;
}

public class TimeDiscount {    
    private Long idOfBook;
    private Integer discountRate;    
}

Set<BookOverallData> booksToReturn
Set<TimeDiscount> actualPromotions
```

The goal is to sum discounts, which means adding `discountRate` from `actualPromotions` to `discountRate` value from the `booksToReturn` list. The objects from both lists can be matched by `idOfBook`.

This is how I solved it

```
booksToReturn.forEach(
            p -> {
                final Optional<TimeDiscount> promotion = actualPromotions.stream().filter(ap -> Objects.equals(ap.getIdOfBook(), p.getIdOfBook())).findFirst();
                promotion.ifPresent(ap -> p.setDiscountRate(ap.getDiscountRate() + p.getDiscountRate()));
            }
        );
```

I'm just exploring streams and I think my solution is clumpy.  How would you solve this problem in more elegant fashion, with usage of streams and functional approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd first create a mapping from `TimeDiscount::getIdOfBook` to `TimeDiscount`:

```
Map<Long, TimeDiscount> accumulator = 
      actualPromotions.stream()
                     .collect(toMap(TimeDiscount::getIdOfBook, Function.identity()));
```

Then I'd do:

```
booksToReturn.forEach(e -> {
       TimeDiscount timeDiscount = accumulator.get(e.getIdOfBook());
       if (timeDiscount != null) e.setDiscountRate(e.getDiscountRate() + timeDiscount.getDiscountRate());
});
```

or if you want to stay with the use of `Optional` for some reason.

```
booksToReturn.forEach(e -> 
       Optional.ofNullable(accumulator.get(e.getIdOfBook()))
          .ifPresent(p -> e.setDiscountRate(e.getDiscountRate() + p.getDiscountRate()))
);
```

This improves upon the inefficient lookup in `actualPromotions.stream()` for each element of `booksToReturn`.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do it is using:

```
booksToReturn.forEach(p -> actualPromotions.stream()
                .filter(actualPromotion -> actualPromotion.getIdOfBook().equals(p.getIdOfBook()))
                .forEach(actualPromotion -> p.setDiscountRate(p.getDiscountRate() + actualPromotion.getDiscountRate())));
```

Assuming `actualPromotion.getIdOfBook()` and `p.getIdOfBook()` would be unique across your `Set`s.

Comment: Nice, but I think it's better to avoid creating stream for each element as @Aomine done it.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this: 
Try this one

```
  Map<Long,Integer> map1 = actualPromotions
   .stream() 
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(TimeDiscount::getIdOfBook,TimeDiscount::getDiscountRate));
```

then use this map in:

```
booksToReturn.stream()
   .filter(b->map1.containsKey(b.getIdOfBook()))
   .map(p->{p.setDiscountRate(map1.get(p.getIdOfBook()) + p.getDiscountRate());return p;}) // .map(p->setSumDiscountRate(map1.get(p.getIdOfBook()) + p.getDiscountRate()))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Try declare a new method in `BookOverallData` class.

```
public BookOverallData setSumDiscountRate(Integer dis){
  this.discountRate = dis;
  return this;
}
```